# Can I use facebook,twitter,linkedin,github icons in my app?

Tags: trademark, social-media

There are a lot of websites on which I login. Many websites offer sign up through fb, twitter, Github etc. I find it difficult to remember through which social account I signed up on a particular website. To solve this problem I developed an Android app on which we can save these details: Name of Account, Linked with (Social Account name), Email address associated to login and retrieve the details anytime. Along with these details I thought of adding the logo of the Social Media account in the app.

Will there be any legal issues I might face for using logos of the websites mentioned in the question.

[image: UI of the app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine as long as you follow each company's requirements for use of their respective logos. Prominent internet companies recognize the value of allowing their icons to be used for such purposes, and provide specific rules to allow such use.

Generally these rules require that the logo or icon not be altered and that it be rendered with specific colors and sizes. Most companies also provide digital assets for you to download and use.

As long as you follow each company's published guidelines, you should not have any problems.

- [Facebook logo usage](https://en.facebookbrand.com/assets/f-logo)
- [Twitter trademark guidelines](https://about.twitter.com/content/dam/about-twitter/company/brand-resources/en_us/Twitter_Brand_Guidelines_V2.0.pdf)
- [LinkedIn Logo usage](https://brand.linkedin.com/visual-identity/logo)

If you think your usage may not meet their requirements, you can always [ask them](https://en.facebookbrand.com/requests/new) [for](http://mailto:trademarks@twitter.com) [permission](https://brand.linkedin.com/content/dam/brand/site/RequestForPermissionToUseLinkedInTrademarks-11.17.2009.pdf).